# Mask Type Error in OpenCV Mean

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to mask out an area of my frame so that I can get the mean of a shape. My code is as follows:

```
for h, cnt in enumerate(contours):
    mask = np.zeros(source_img.shape, np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], 0, 255, -1)
    print mask
    print mask.dtype
    mean = cv2.mean(source_img, mask=mask)
```

However, when running this code, I get `error: (-215) mask.empty() || mask.type() == CV_8U in function mean`.

The print statements included come back that it is `uint8`. The print of the mask itself prints out a non-empty numpy array with values of 0 and 255. Any other ideas of where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Whoops. Forgot to include that piece. No, not empty. The drawContours works just fine, and the print of the mask prints out a numpy array with 0/255 values in it. I'll update Q.

Comment: is it valid for all your iterations? print out also mask.sum() or whatever to know that.. if one is zero, that's the problem

Comment: It only runs for the first iteration before breaking, but the sum of the mask is non-zero.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rookie mistake: As it turns out, the source image that I took the shape from was a colored image, which meant that `source_img.shape()` came out to `(480, 640, 3)`. So despite then setting the type of the mask correctly, it was still a 3 channel image, when it needed to be two.

Fixed by doing my initialization of the mask layer as:

```
mask = np.zeros(source_img.shape[:2], np.uint8)
```